# Azure ad login issue we couldn't sign in you

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have issue in azure ad authentication when I build application using visual studio 2017 integration with azure ad and deployed in to azure.

the problem is when sign using our aazure ad to login username and password after that they send token our mobile when we enter that toke some my applixation is working,  some time error we couldn't sign you try again could you tell me issue.this issue is coming time to time.

when I rebuild project and deployed again it is working next with two hours same error is coming I couldn't find the solution why this error occured could please help me

Comment: Might be token expiration issue! can you check the token (bearer) in jwt.ms.

Comment: How we can check token in mvc c# .how we handle token issue can you provide any code

Comment: using fiddler or browser dev tool.

Comment: when it's redirecting back from Microsoft site, there will be some entries in local/session storage in the browser.

Comment: How to clear mvc

Comment: Hello manish I checked the token -1 coming how we can solve

Comment: can you check the exp of the token? you can decode the token in jwt.ms

Comment: How we can check token expire in mvc startup class

Comment: @kandeepansabanathan also please share full error details (code, request or correlation id, timestamp), type of user account (personal, work or school), broweser used.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been fixed in ASP.NET core and in the new version of Katana Owin for ASP.NET. To resolve this issue, you can upgrade your application to use ASP.NET Core. If you must continue stay on ASP.NET, perform the following:

Update your application’s `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package be at least version and modify your code to use one of the new cookie manager classes, for example something like the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
{ 
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies", 
    CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager() 
});
```

> How we can check token expire in mvc startup class

You could use [`Properties.ExpiresUtc`](https://github.com/mderriey/aspnet-core-token-renewal/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs) to get the access token expiration time.

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = x =>
    {
        x.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
        var accessToken = new JwtSecurityToken(x.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);
        x.Properties.ExpiresUtc = accessToken.ValidTo;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

Also you could silent renew `access_token` via `refresh_token` in asp.net core mvc, refer to this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60005317/silent-renew-access-token-via-refresh-token-in-asp-net-core-mvc).

Comment: This helped me a lot, after the user sign out, when sign in again, I received the error Unable to connect it at this time. Try again later, that fixed it.